# How to aggregate and group by in each column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
major minor
  A     a
  A     a
  A     b
  B     c
  B     d
```

I'd like to summarize `major` and `minor` columns to get this result:

```
major minor major_count minor_count
A       a      3          2
A       b      3          1             
B       c      2          1
B       d      2          1
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I tried:

```
select major, minor,count(major),count(minor)
from table group by 1,2
```

But it didn't count each number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve this using window functions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    major as major,
    minor as minor,
    count(major) over (partition by major) as major_count,
    count(minor) over (partition by minor) as minor_count
FROM
    my_table
ORDER BY
    major,minor;
```

| major | minor | major_count | minor_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 3 | 2 |
| A | b | 3 | 1 |
| B | c | 2 | 1 |
| B | d | 2 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5s4ujaenuwwGZPrbY8yGa5/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select major, minor,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by major) as major_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by minor) as minor_count
from t
group by major, minor;
```